# How to get the locations of all the points on a line WP8.1 Silverlight c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am drawing a line onto the canvas, by giving it a starting and ending point. Now I want to get the X and Y location of each point of that line. how can I do that?

```
Line line = new Line();
        line.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        line.StrokeThickness =1;

        line.X1 = x[1];
        line.X2 = y[1];
        line.Y1 = x[i-1]/4;
        line.Y2 = y[i - 1] / 4;
        MyIP.Children.Add(line);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple math. You know the starting and ending point of the line, meaning you can calculate any point you want on that line, by using the equation of the line.  The way to get the equation is

```
y = y1 + [(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)] * (x - x1)
```

You know 2 points: (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)

In the end you'll get something in the form of

```
y = Ax + B
```

Meaning that for every x, you can calculate y, as A & B are constants.

So you could simply loop through all the x values, and increment by whatever granularity you want or need, to get the appropriate y values, and you'll end up with a set of (x, y) values

```
for (double i = x1; i <= x2; i+=0.2)
{
    var x = i;
    var y = (A*x)+B;
    // now you have one pair of x, y 
}
```